# Why my condition execs always the first option?

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

I made this condition related to hours and minutes, but it doesn´t matter when you use it, it will always exec the first option.

```
case "salecs":

  let dt = new Date();
  let hr = dt.getHours();
  let min = dt.getMinutes();
  let tie = `${hr}${min}`;
  let ti = parseInt(tie);

  if (ti < 1429 && ti > 1229) {
    message.reply('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almuerzo')
  }else if (ti < 2129 && ti > 2029) {
      message.reply('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cena')
  }else
    message.channel.send('Salen esos tiritos? \nht \n@everyone');
  break;
```

Comment: it runs the third option for me, though you are missing braces on your last `else`

Comment: Did you try to log `ti` and see what value it contains when you run this?

Comment: @pilchard oh sorry i forgot to put it here, but it is in the code

Comment: @Ivar from the server console it says it is 145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, I have added a sample below by attaching the value to a string variable, maybe you have tested it in wrong timings, you will have to modify timings to get valid outputs. I have also added samples in which I updated time as required.

```js
function getStr(ti) {
  let str = "";
  if (ti < 1429 && ti > 1229) {
    str = 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almuerzo';
  } else if (ti < 2129 && ti > 2029) {
    str = 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cena';
  } else
    str = 'Salen esos tiritos? \nht \n@everyone';
  return str;
}

console.log(getStr(1233));
console.log(getStr(2030));
console.log(getStr(1111));

let dt = new Date();
let hr = dt.getHours();
let min = dt.getMinutes();
let tie = `${hr}${min}`;
let ti = parseInt(tie);

console.log(getStr(ti));
dt = new Date();
hr = dt.getHours(dt.setHours(14));
min = dt.getMinutes(dt.setMinutes(20));
tie = `${hr}${min}`;
ti = parseInt(tie);
console.log(getStr(ti));

dt = new Date();
hr = dt.getHours(dt.setHours(20));
min = dt.getMinutes(dt.setMinutes(40));
tie = `${hr}${min}`;
ti = parseInt(tie);
console.log(getStr(ti));
```